# How to pass html script variable to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Just a quick question. Suppose I obtain values for var `name` and `size` in html `<script>` tag like this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_files), how can I pass them to angularJS controller?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So This is NOT an elegant solution but you can use it as a global variable but you can do

```
window.myVar = varinScript;
```

and in the controller use/asign the `window.myVar` to a controller variable

Hope it helps